# Cannot access project properties in VS2022 17.8.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3, I cannot get to the project properties page to change the target framework. When I select  Properties under Project, nothing happens.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Visual Studio Installer to repair or update Visual Studio.

**Update:**

[image]

**Repair:**

[image]

Comment: I used Visual Studio installer as suggested and did a repair which fixed the problem.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.